# How to set off background color reflection?

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, world

I'm very new to blender. I animated this model:

[image: Screenshot]

I want to use this animation in a video. I use chroma key to take away the background but it's impossible to do this when the green color from the background reflects on the door(see image). I did change the Environment and Indirect lighting but it did'nt help. I tried many things but nothing worked. Can someone help me out?

EDIT
I'm in blender render mode.

Comment: Using a green background is completely unnecessary. You should be able to export a clean alpha channel out of blender.

Comment: If you wan't to use a video format that doesn't support alpha, you can also render out a black and white matte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Don't have to use chroma,You can just render the video in alpha channel.

### Cycles:

---

**To do so,You just have to check transparent  film panel:**
[image: T]

This will render the background as Alpha but the reflections will be still here.

**To remove the colored reflection,Uncheck use Environment in render layer:**

[image: U]

### Blender Internal:

---

**You just have to Uncheck Sky in render layers:**

[image: S]

Comment: Thank you, but is it possible too in "blender-render"?

Comment: Sorry, I did already: same result

Comment: You did the process under the blender Internal?Can you add another screenshot after the Sky checked?

Comment: -1 This doesn't actually answer the asked question. Adding alternate suggestions for a better method to achieve an end result is okay; however, answering the actual question is also important, since other people may read this question and still want to achieve, for different reasons, what the question originally asked to do.

Comment: @GiantCowFilms I answered the question without any alternatives,he never said anything about file format,Most of us probably render a PNG image sequence not a video anyway.

Comment: @GiantCowFilms I thinks is perfectly legit, and expected of this site, to suggest alternatives that are considered a better workflow than the one proposed by the OP.

Comment: @cegaton yes, but the original request result should still be achived, which was not.

Comment: @OmarAhmad, the question asked how to create a colored background without having the color appear in reflections. He implied a particular use for that, but still, the question was not about rendering transparent backgrounds.

Comment: @GiantCowFilms when you disable sky in the render layers everything that is related to it is one including reflections,same in cycles when you disable environment the refection wont be here,So I pretty much answered his question.

Comment: @OmarAhmad But the background is black, not green.

Comment: @GiantCowFilms It is alpha not black,he car alpha over a green color easily,I don't think it is a problem.

Comment: @GiantCowFilms and Omar Ahmed: Anyway, this answer was'nt the solution for me but it was a good answer. I can't input transparent video's in to my video editing program. I let this rest for a few days and two days ago I found my solution, to do it with the compositor.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are trying can be accomplished by turning off everything except Camera in the ray visibility window in the world menu.

Answer (score 0):

[image: settings]

For anyone who still sees this in Blender 2.8: go to *Materials -> Surface* and there you can set the strength to "*Is Camera Ray*".